# Tsrange - Calculating the difference between two ranges

Tags: postgresql, range, timestamp-with-timezone

I have two tables `free_time` and `appointment`. Both contain tsranges.

How do I write a query (or function) that determines the actual free time after "subtracting" the difference the `appointment` from the `freetime`?

```
INSERT INTO free_time(freetime)
VALUES('[2017-04-19 09:00, 2017-04-19 12:30)');

INSERT INTO appointment(appointment)
VALUES('[2017-04-19 10:30, 2017-04-19 11:30)');
```

I want the result to be something like:

```
["2017-04-19 9:00","2017-04-19 10:30:00"), 
["2017-04-19 11:30:00","2017-04-19 12:30:00")
```

Comment: Are appointments guaranteed to be a subset of freetime?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to break apart the range, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

> The union and difference operators will fail if the resulting range would need to contain two disjoint sub-ranges, as such a range cannot be represented.

In order to do this you can use [`lower`, and `upper`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

```
SELECT tsrange(  lower(freetime), lower(appointment)  )  AS before_appointment,
       tsrange(  upper(appointment), upper(freetime)  )  AS after_appointment
FROM ( VALUES
  (
    '[2017-04-19 09:00, 2017-04-19 12:30)'::tsrange,
    '[2017-04-19 10:30, 2017-04-19 11:30)'::tsrange
  )
) AS t(freetime,appointment)
WHERE freetime @> appointment;

              before_appointment               |               after_appointment               
-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 ["2017-04-19 09:00:00","2017-04-19 10:30:00") | ["2017-04-19 11:30:00","2017-04-19 12:30:00")
(1 row)
```

Comment: @JonathanEustace keep in mind this only works if the appointment fits in the freetime range.

Comment: I have another more complex question, perhaps I should have asked it first. What if I had a table of rows of freetime ranges and a table of rows of appointment ranges? I want all the freetimes available after subtracting the appointments. How would I construct that? If you wish I can make another question of it.

Comment: Yes, make another question out of  it with sample data.

Comment: Making it now, probably will take about 15 minutes. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have added the question.